# TypeError: All provided fields *must* be text when bytes mode is off; got 'CN=XXX,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, ldap

I am trying to create a new Model using the django-ldapdb library. When I try to run python manage.py makemigrations, it tells me that the bytes mode is off. I do not really know where this is and how to activate it.

This is my model:

```
class LdapUser(ldapdb.models.Model):
    base_dn = "CN=XXX,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
    object_classes = ['posixAccount', 'shadowAccount', 'inetOrgPerson']

    phone = CharField(db_column='telephoneNumber', blank=True)
    mobile_phone = CharField(db_column='mobile', blank=True)
```

I looked it up, but could not find anything helpful. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a unicode string for `base_dn`:

```
base_dn = u"CN=XXX,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: It’s the first line of your model, just add the `u` prefix